# Difference between module-layered-navigation-staging and module-layered-navigation

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, magento2-enterprise, staging

In magento 2 enterprise edition,there are two modules for layered navigation :
**module-layered-navigation-staging** and **module-layered-navigation**.

What is the difference between these two modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is Magento Staging Module?**

a set of functionality that enables you to schedule the store changes in Magento database. You can configure the particular state of the database to be applied in the future

> Magento_Staging module is a framework for other staging modules. It
>   declares basic scenarios over the content, while other staging modules
>   perform them. (You can recognize a staging modules by name, each ends
>   with “Staging” and starts with a name of a module, which it extends.
>   For example, Magento_CatalogStaging module extends functionality of
>   Magento_Catalog module.)

For more info visit below link

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/mrg/ee/Staging.html

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/mrg/ee/LayeredNavigationStaging.html